# How do you usually comment your merges in mercurial (solo developer, only one external repo in bitbucket)?

Tags: mercurial, merge

When I have to commit merges I've done in mercurial, I just do `hg commit -m "Merge."`

What do you usually do when Merging? Do you write the changesets in a comment, or try to write "meaningfull" comments (since I think they are useless, except when you're doing merges from two really different repos in different locations).

Is it possible to create an alias in mercurial (like hgmerge) in [alias] in hgrc, that automatically does `hg commit -m "Merge: heads ${head}, ${head} ..."`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be easy to create that alias (I'll do it below) but it's also of almost no value.  It's very easy to pull the parent1 and parent2 values out of a merge changeset, so it's not really telling you anything more than just "merge" would.

Personally, even on single person repos I try to put something at least halfway useful even if it's just something like these:

- merging configuration work into code
- merging work from desktop into work from laptop
- merging away an anonymous branch I didn't like
- forgot to pull/update before editing

There's always some reason history diverged, even if it's a totally mundane reason like forgetting to update or working disconnected at the coffeeshop, and that's what I note.

That said you could do this:

```
hg commit -m "merging: $(hg parents --template '{node|short}\n') | xargs"
```

which you sould make a shell alias with:

```
[aliases]
mycommit = !$HG hg commit -m "merging: $(hg parents --template '{node|short}\n') | xargs"
```

Allowing you to run `hg mycommit`, but just dig for the better description.

P.S. Someone is going to suggest the `fetch` extension.  Ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

When I'm merging after a pull, I usually only write something like "merge after pull". When I must correct something after the merge, I'll precisely describe what I did so my coworkers can understand the changes.

When I'm merging a branch in another, I precise the two branches on the commit message "merging branch1 in branch2".

As for the alias, sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: Yeah, I know telling which branches are bein merged is a good idea, I'm looking for an automated way of doing it, maybe with an alias.